How to find the substrings in MongoDB
I have data in my db in the form:
{term: "Hello how"}, {term: "whoever"}, {term:"what"}

I have an array of strings like:
["Hello how are you", "whoever has done this please let me know"]

I want to write a query in mongo db that will fetch all the substrings for these array of strings in the fastest way.
So the result I'm expecting for this is ["Hello how","whoever"]
I have tried with regex:
Hello|how|are|you|whoever|has|done|this|please|let|me|know

but this did not work because this matched individual words
Edit:
Clarifications:

Each term is in a separate document.
Eg:

{id:1,term: "Hello how"}
{id:2,term: "whoever"}
{id:3,term:"what"}


The array of strings is fetched from an external source and needs to be part of the query. The array of strings will vary every time.

The term should be a substring of any of the strings from the array of strings and not necessarily a prefix.

The query that I have tried:


db.collection.find({
  text: { $regex: /Hello|how|are|you|whoever|has|done|this|please|let|me|know/, $options: 'i' }
})


Provide example data. Are those term items in a single document or separate documents? Are these always prefix matches? Or do you want to match anywhere in the string? Show what you have tried so far (your current actual query). Read: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Per @aneroid's comment, you should associate more details to clarify the ambiguity like should it be full phrase match.
Here is the closest I can guess. This relies on a sub-pipeline lookup with checking on $indexOfCP to locate the term.
db.source.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "term",
      "let": {
        s: "$string"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$ne": [
                -1,
                {
                  "$indexOfCP": [
                    "$$s",
                    "$term"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "result"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "result": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$result",
          "initialValue": "",
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $eq: [
                  "$$value",
                  ""
                ]
              },
              "then": "$$this.term",
              "else": {
                "$concat": [
                  "$$value",
                  " ",
                  "$$this.term"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground
